# Select Values based on Distinct Dates

Tags: mysql

I am puzzled for a while now. I have a table with phone numbers and dates(Timestamp). If a number exists more than once for a particular date, the number should be returned only once.

```
           Date               Number
     2013-05-14 15:39:19     1234567890
     2013-05-14 15:39:19     1234567890
     2013-05-14 15:39:19     9876543210
     2013-05-14 15:39:20     1234567890
```

**Output:**

```
           Date               Number
    2013-05-14 15:39:19     1234567890
    2013-05-14 15:39:19     9876543210
    2013-05-14 15:39:20     1234567890
```

I know this doesn't serve my need but i tried `select * from table name group by Date` and didn't get the desired result as expected. How should I go about?

Comment: don't you want to group by number?

Comment: what if the same number is present in two different dates? then group by number will not work i guess. Am i correct?

Comment: group by both, then... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select * from table name group by Date,Number
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d6c5/1)